# Fatou's lemma. Examples with limit inferior $\neq$ lim.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have problems with understanding Fatou's Lemma.
What is the reason for using $\liminf$?
Can someone please give an example where $\liminf \neq \lim$.
When the reason does not depend on one of the two sides of the lemma, it is good to give an example when $\lim f_n \neq \liminf f_n$ and one when $\lim \mu(f_n) \neq \liminf \mu(f_n)$.
Then I can see why $\liminf$ is used instead of $\lim$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take two examples:

Example 1: Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Take $f_{2n}=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $f_{2n+1}=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$.
Here note that $f=0$, and so it's integral is equal to $0$. Now, $f_{n}$'s all have integral infinity. If we just restrict our attention to $[0,1]$ say, then of course, the RHS from Fatou's lemma is $0$.

Example 2: Counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. Take $a_{2n}=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$, and $a_{2n+1}=0$.

Here, $f=0$ again, and so is the RHS.

Apply Fatou's lemma and see what conclusions you get. Note that the limit doesn't exist in either case.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please state the two conclusions which follows from Fatou's lemma for these examples, so that I can check if I really understand it correctly.

Comment: @user202723: Sure, let me add them.

Comment: I understand it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence $a_n$ ain't convergent $\lim a_n$ doesn't exist, $\liminf a_n$ always exists, so proving something using $\liminf$ is actually a stronger result.

If $a_n$ is convergent $\lim a_n = \liminf a_n$.

Comment: voldemort has given examples in his answer.